# Continuous touch detection in Android

Tags: java, android, touch

I am developing an android game. I have the following code to check if my finger is on the screen

`if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)`
            `this.downPressed=false;`
         `else`
             `this.downPressed=true;`

`if(this.downPressed) {`
`//move the object`
`}`

I checked using `Log.e("Motion",String.valueOf(e.getAction()));` 
When I initially place my finger on the screen, ACTION_DOWN is detected.

Then when I still have my finger on the screen, few traces of ACTION_MOVE is detected

Then when I still have my finger on the screen, nothing is detected

Finally when I take my finger off the screen, ACTION_UP is detected

I am not able to successfully detect anything when my finger is laid still on the screen. Please help me in detecting  this continuous touch.

Comment: You know the finger is still on the screen since an ACTION_UP event has not fired. Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can just keep track of which state you are in with a boolean flag.

Comment: why would you get any events whenn your finger doesent move?

Comment: @dcharms yes, downPressed is my boolean flag. I set it to false when ACTION_UP; else it should stay true. But since these come within onTouchEvent(), it doesnt help

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: @pskink Yes, It doesnt move; but i am touching the screen right? How to check that I am continuously touching the screen?

Comment: @dcharms I have a 3d model which should continue to move when I touch the screen. If i keep touching the screen, it should keep moving

Comment: @David right,  you are touching the screen,  if nothing changes,  nothing is sent,  btw how offten the os would sent it:  one per sec, 1000 times per sec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be doing the move logic inside your onTouch event method. Rather, like you are currently doing, set a flag when TOUCH_DOWN is detected and clear when TOUCH_UP is fired. Then make an update handler that continuously runs. If the flag is set it moves the object.

Comment: 'public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {  if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
         {
          downPressed=true;
          handler.post(repeater);
          
                   
         }
         if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
         {
          downPressed=false;
        
         }}

Comment: Runnable repeater = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             
             manualMove(true,touch_x, touch_y);
             if (downPressed) {
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
             }
         }
     };